# __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given) Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have been uploading a new version of my app engine application and after uploading when I make a request I get this as a response:

```
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1076, in __call__
    handler = self.handler(request, response)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

I have no idea what to do at all, I've commented parts of my code, uncommented them, I've uploaded the code to different GAE apps I have, even multiple versions of those apps.

I dont even know where to start can anyone please tell me what this error could even mean? I will provide any information you request, thank you in advance.

EDIT:
This is what the handler that i have added looks like:

```
class GCMRegister(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        regid = self.request.get("regId")
        if not regid:
            self.response.out.write('Must specify regid')
        else:
            u = usuario()
            u.name = "deadlybacon" # ax_length = 140)
            u.mail = "testmail@hotmail.com" # (max_length = 256, db_index = True
            u.password = "password" #max_length = 140)
            u.put()
            u.push_key(regid)
```

My WSGIApplication looks like this:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),

    ('/indexData', indexData),
    ('/ajaxLogIn', ajaxLogIn),
    ('/createGroup', createGroup),
    ('/masterServices', masterServices),
    ('/groupInfo', groupInfo),
    ('/groupInviteTo', groupInviteTo),
    ('/acceptNotif', acceptNotif),
    ('/adventureCreate', createAdventure),  
    ('/adventureAppointTo', adventureAppointTo), 
    ('/addNewPrueba', addNewPrueba), 
    ('/listPoolPruebas', listPoolPruebas), 
    ('/addExistingPrueba', addExistingPrueba), 

    ('/gcm/register', GCMRegister),

]) #, debug=True, config = config)
```

at first I assumed it was the debug and config, that is why i commented it, it makes no difference, the same error happens no matter what

Comment: And what does your handler look like? I think you forgot to add the `request` and `response` arguments to your class `__init__` method.

Comment: ive just editted the question, there it is, its just like the other handlers im just baffled idk whats happening

Comment: And how is the handler registered?

Comment: @DeadlyBacon: Do you have any additional methods defined on the `GCMRegister` class?

Comment: also @MartijnPieters I'm not sure I understand your question, do you mean like what my webapp2.WSGIApplication thingy looks like?

Comment: @DeadlyBacon: yes, those are the URL registrations.

Comment: I'd bet that somewhere you've redefined the provided __init__() method to one with only 1 parameter, and when the class is initialized the new method can't accept the three arguments passed that the webapp2 controller.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have just editted the OP, including my WSGIApplication.

Comment: @Mario nope, not really, could this be a version issue? has anything changed in the WSGIApplication class in the latest version of GAE?

Comment: If that were the case (which I can assure is not) all developers would be having this issue, and not only you. Furthermore it's happening to you with only that method, the rest work OK, yeah?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class HomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, response):
        self.initialize(request, response)
        ...
```